# ERROR code 201: missing user password when creating anonymous user: Parse.com REST API

Tags: swift, rest, parse-platform

I am trying to sign up an anonymous user using REST API. I found several discussion regarding linking Twitter/Facebook users that share the same problem but none gave this solution.

According to [Parse.com REST API Doc](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#users-linking-users), you only need to provide some sort of id to the `authData`, i.e UDID, but it complains that there is no password. This is the error:

> "{"code":201,"error":"missing user password"}

This is my code:

```
func registerAnonymisUserWithComplitionHandler(deviceUDID:String, onComplition: RESTResponse){
let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("APP ID", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
request.addValue("API Key", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-REST-API-Key")
request.addValue("1", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Revocable-Session")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let urlString = "https://api.parse.com"
let baseURL = NSURL(string: urlString)
let url = NSURL(string: "/1/users", relativeToURL: baseURL!)

request.URL = url

let param = ["authData": ["anonymous":["id":deviceUDID]]]

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
do {
    request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(param, options: .PrettyPrinted)
} catch {
    print("error")
}

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (data, response, error) in
    if (error == nil){
        do {
            let tmpUserDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
            print(tmpUserDictionary)


            let statusResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            onComplition(jsonDictionary: tmpUserDictionary, response: statusResponse, error: nil)
        } catch {

        }
    } else {
        onComplition(jsonDictionary: nil, response: nil, error: error)
    }
}
task.resume()
}
```

Thanks to Muhammad Junaid Butt, I have fixed a small issue in the `param` and it works.

Comment: Why don't you use Parse iOS SDK?
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidButt thanks for your comment. This would be the easy solution but my app needs to be build purely on REST API. The reason I need the above, is because I have another problem which is listed as a question, and I think this can solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845398/parse-com-error-code-999-rest-api-user-signup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the attached screenshot. I used REST API of PARSE to create an Anonymous user and it is working fine. (I used Postman for testing this).

[image]

Comment: @TalZion Thanks for accepting my answer. I would suggest you to use AFNetworking or Alamofire to handle web-services.